# How to decide is a Process Object Is Running

Tags: c#, process, system.diagnostics

While googlin im having only Information how to get All Processes ,store into `Process[]` ,but what i need is :

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.startInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
proc.Start();
```

Below i created a Process Object ,now i need to know if this Process is Closed ,exactly this one because if User Closes and if i try from Code `proc.Exit();` it throws an Exception .

So far im doing like :

```
    Process procs = new Process();
    Process[] proc = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process p in proc)
    {
        if (p.Id = procs.Id)
        { 
            //Do Something
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`HasExited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx) on your `Process` object:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.startInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
proc.Start();

// do something

if(proc.HasExited)
    // notepad was closed
```

Or, if you want to be notified as soon as the process has been closed, use the [`Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.startInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
proc.Exited += ProcessExited;
proc.Start();

private void ProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // notepad was closed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line:

```
proc.Exited += new EventHandler(proc_Exited);
```

Then such method:

```
void proc_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //process has ended..
}
```

You can have your own global flag, and raise it in the handler or handle it "live" depends on what is your final goal.